# I am trying to build a sql view in sqlplus and get the following error

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sql-view, oracle11gr2

CREATE VIEW V_SALES_REPORT AS SELECT Sales_ID, Sales_Date, Product_ID, Product_Name, Quantity_Sold, Product_Unit_Price, Sales_Price_Per_Unit, (Sales_Price_Per_Unit - Product_Unit_Price) Profit_Amount FROM TBL_STOCK NATURAL JOIN TBL_SALES ORDER BY Profit_Amount DESC, Sales_ID ASC;

got the error:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
[the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfpyq.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi! Could you please copy/paste the SQL query instead of the picture?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a whitespace between the `as` and `select`:

```
CREATE VIEW v_sales_report AS SELECT
-- This was missing ---------^
```

Comment: yes. that was resolved. thank you. please check the new error